# Rails - models with same class name, but one is inside a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm adding a model to my project which shares a name with a class in the `models` directory, but it's in a `module` and has no relation (figuratively and literally) to the existing model: `Offer` and `Partner::Offer`.

```
+ app
|-+ models
  |-- offer.rb
  |-+ partner
    |- offer.rb
```

I generated the new model using `rails new model Partner::Offer`, and it generated the appropriate migration and FactoryBot factory, as well as the `Partner` module:

```rb
module Partner
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'partner_'
  end
end
```

Now, here's where I'm running into some weird behavior. I fired up the Rails console and tried to build a new Partner::Offer using the factory:

```rb
offer = FactoryBot.build(:partner_offer)
```

This returns an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'external_id=' for #<Partner::Offer:0x0000000113622910>`. `external_id` is an attribute on the top-level `Offer` model, but not on `Partner::Offer`.

It seems like the factory is instead trying to build the top-level `Offer` object instead. As a sanity check, I just typed in `Partner::Offer.new` and observed the results, and while the Class of the new object was correct, it had all the fields of the top-level `Offer` class.

I've never seen this behavior before. What could be causing the mix-up?

This is the `Partner::Offers` factory file:

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :partner_offer, class: 'Partner::Offer' do
    partner_id { SecureRandom.hex }
    expiration_date { 1.week.from_now }
    amount { 123.45 }
  end
end
```

Comment: How `Partner::Offer` looks?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was.

I have a `clients` folder in my project, which is a sibling of the `models` folder. And I have a client class there that shares a namespace with the Offer:

```rb
module Partner
  class Client
    ...
  end
end
```

It seems that this file is conflicting with the `Partner` module file. I fixed it by changing that module into a class under the `Partner` namespace:

```rb
class Partner::Base < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true

  def self.table_name_prefix
    'partner_'
  end
end

class Partner::Offer < Partner::Base
  ...
end
```

Everything works fine now.